# Attempting to draw rectangles multithreaded

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am attempting to draw about 3600 points on a form, it is pretty slow using one thread so I decided I want to use 4 threads for it.

In my code I divide the 3600 points to the 4 threads and they are supposed to draw it. however for some reason an ArgumentOutOfRangeException is being thrown.
I tried to debug my code but I couldn't find the mistake.

here is the code :

(Ignore the class _3DPoint, it is just a point that has x,y,z values. when I draw them I only use the x,y values.)

**code for drawing the points :**

```
    public Graphics g; //g = this.CreateGraphics() in form1.Load()
    public void drawrectangle(_3DPoint)
        float xCord = float.Parse(p.x.ToString());
        float yCord = float.Parse(p.y.ToString());
        Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        xCord = lsize * xCord + center.X;
        yCord = lsize * yCord + 10 + center.Y;
        g.FillRectangle(b, xCord, yCord, 2, 2);
    }
```

lsize, center are just variables for aligning the points as I want them.

**All of the multithread action code:**

```
    public List<_3DPoint[]> multiThreadsdata = new List<_3DPoint[]>();
    public void handlemultithread(_3DPoint[] P)
    {
        g.Clear(Color.Black);
        for (int i = 0; i < multiThreads.Length; i++)
        {
            multiThreadsdata.Add(new _3DPoint[P.Length / multiThreads.Length]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < multiThreads.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = (P.Length / multiThreads.Length) * (i); j < (P.Length / multiThreads.Length) * (i + 1); j++)
            {
                multiThreadsdata[i][j - ((P.Length / multiThreads.Length) * i)] = new _3DPoint(P[j]);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < multiThreads.Length; i++)
        {
            multiThreads[i] = new Thread(() => drawPoints(multiThreadsdata[i]));
            multiThreads[i].Start();
        }
    }
    delegate void SetCallBackPoint(_3DPoint location);
    public void drawPoints(_3DPoint[] locations)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < locations.Length; i++)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetCallBackPoint e = new SetCallBackPoint(drawrectangle);
                this.Invoke(e, new object[] { locations[i] });
            }
            else
            {
                drawrectangle(locations[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

`P` is a _3DPoint array that contains all the 3600 points.

`mutliThreads` is a Thread[] containing 4 threads.

I get the exception in `handlemultithread` method. in the third line of this  `for` loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < multiThreads.Length; i++)
        {
            multiThreads[i] = new Thread(() => drawPoints(multiThreadsdata[i])); // <- here.
            multiThreads[i].Start();
        }
```

I don't know what is the problem, my guess is that there is some problem with the multithreading because I'm just a beginner with multithreading.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Winforms UI isn't multi-threaded, and you can't draw on the same GDI+ surface from multiple threads at the same time either. Multi-threading is hard and expensive - be very careful about guessing your way around, it's a great way to get tons of subtle bugs that are hard to track and fix. Not to mention that since you're doing `Invoke` anyway, you marshall every single draw back on the UI thread, wasting tons of resources while keeping your actual workload 100% single-threaded. Overall, there's a lot of performance issues in your code - multi-threading shouldn't be the first thing you try.

Comment: "this.CreateGraphics" is bad, use event Paint and e.Graphics inside, and activate DoubleBuffered=true. You will see increase of performance.

Comment: Using threads to make something "faster" will leave you disappointed all day long.

Comment: @MattWilko I'll go back to a single thread, and I'll try to use x... suggestions for this. I'll see how it goes.

Comment: Don't create brushes for each point, either, if you can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is entirely possible to Draw 3600 rectangles quickly on a form when you apply the suggestions in the comments.

If that doesn't give you enough time you can consider creating Images on  a single background thread, store them in some sort of buffer until they are needed to e painted on the `Graphics` object of the `Paint` event of the form. That is only feasible if you can know upfront what needs to be painted on the next frame.

This example uses a simple Background worker to fill an [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) with images. The comments in the code explain what is going on.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static ConcurrentQueue<Image>  buffer = new ConcurrentQueue<Image>();
    static Random r = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        // this is already a great performance win ...
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img =null;
        // get from buffer ..
        if (!buffer.TryDequeue(out img))
        {
            // nothing available
            // direct random
            for (var x = 0; x < e.ClipRectangle.Width; x++)
            {
                for (var y = 0; y < e.ClipRectangle.Height; y++)
                {
                    using (var pen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r.Next(255), r.Next(255), r.Next(255)))))
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, x, y, 1, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // otherwise Draw the prepared image
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img,0,0);
            Trace.WriteLine(buffer.Count);
            img.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // force a repaint of the Form
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // as long as the form is not disposed
        while (!IsDisposed)
        {
            // we keep 60 images in memory
            if (buffer.Count < 60)
            {
                // bitmap
                var bmp = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height);
                var img = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
                // draw
                for (int i = 0; i < 3600; i++)
                {
                    using (var pen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(r.Next(255), r.Next(255), r.Next(255)))))
                    {
                        img.DrawRectangle(pen, r.Next(Width),r.Next(Height), r.Next(Width), r.Next(Height));
                    }
                }
                // store the drawing in the buffer
                buffer.Enqueue(bmp);
            }
            else
            {
                // simple and naive way to give other threads a bit of room
                Thread.Sleep(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that when you have a CPU heavy process adding more threads will not by magic make your methods run quicker. You might even make it worse: more threads compete for time on the CPU.

Comment: This solution is very helpfull, but I'm going to increase the amount of point by 10-15 to make the graphics more detailed. I thought if there is a way to assign the drawing part to the GPU instead of letting the CPU do it ? Note : I cannot predict what will the next image be like.
Thanks.

Comment: I just checked how quick your code, and it's not quick enough. I might had to mention that I need it to draw fast enough that if the user presses a button it will change quick enough so it will look fluent to the eye.

Comment: I'm moving a 3d function on the screen. including left right up down, and rotations in the x-axis, y-axis and the z-axis. there are about 10 - 12 buttons for the movement.

Comment: Ok, well, for that kind of stuff GDI lacks any support, there is no magic for that in System.Drawing.

Comment: Unfortunate. I'll mark your answer as correct since it is a pretty good performance upgrade. Thanks alot.